# DecimalFormat weird behavior with pattern #####0.00 in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, format, decimalformat

I am using below code snap to display `float` price value with two decimal points.

```
NumberFormat FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("#####0.00");
float myFloatValue =\\I am able to fetch this value dynamically
String finalPrice = FORMAT.format(myFloatValue);
// I am using this String (finalPrice) for export xml purpose.
```

It seems working fine normally, but I have noticed some examples(given below) where it is not working properly and produce the price with more than two decimal points. I am not able to replicate it again, I can see it in only log files.

Some examples output of `finalPrice` String : **0.10999966**,  **0.1800003**, **0.45999908**.

Can anybody help me to guess original value of `myFloatValue` from these outputs? So that it will help me to replicate the scenario and fix it.

Comment: What is the input for your example?

Comment: That is actually my question, I am getting output in log directly and not able to replicate, so I need input for my float value.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia my previous answer was invalid then, sorry for that. I cannot replicate the problem, but, if it helps, in case you haven't noticed, in the three cases that you describe, the following four digits are either 0's or 9's. Is there any condition (if/while/for) under which the numbers are formatted, otherwise not?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind about this is the well known precission bug in the `double` primitive datatype. But the `DecimalFormat` API is guranteed to return just the number of digits specified in the template. Are you sure the data in the log come from the values returned by `DecimalFormat.format` ?

Comment: First, you are using floats (double is not a solution either) to model prices. *DO NOT USE FLOATING-POINTS FOR DECIMAL VALUES LIKE MONEY, ALWAYS USE BIGDECIMAL*. floats instead doubles are even worse because you will losing digits if the amount of price goes over 16 million. Second, your DecimalFormat seems to be ok, so what JDK version are you using and what machine (Windows, Linux, Mac, Android ?)

Comment: @ThorstenS. JDK 1.7 (Linux)

Answer (score 2):

The sporadic occurrence makes me wonder whether the DECIMAL_FORMAT is used in several threads concurrently. That is a no-no. However one would expect 
*wrong* values too.

Maybe for good order also specify a fixed Locale (decimal point vs. comma, thousand separators).

And finally `float` or even `double` are not suited for financial software: those numbers are approximations.

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("9.99");
price = price.multiply(BigDecimal.TWO); // 19.98 exact
```

BigDecimal is a PITA for writing calculations, but keeps its precision.